# Can't install lucida fonts with texlive on macOS

Tags: mac, lucida, texlive-2023

I purchased Lucida fonts (type1) from Y&Y (now defunct) and MathTime Pro fonts from PCTeX.

I have a directory (TDS compliant, I think) "localtexmf" where I have all the .pfb files and I think all is needed for using the fonts.

Indeed I have used that directory with MikTeX under WIN for years with different machines and, following the appropriate instructions and steps, I have been always able to use both fonts (mtpro and lucida).

Then, I purchased a M1 iMac and installed on that MikTeX and I added the "localtexmf", and I went through all the steps I knew about and, again, BOTH fonts work (mtpro and lucida).

Finally, I just purchased one M1 MacBook Air on which I decided (why?) to install MacTeX (which is basically TeXLive, AFAK) and then I followed the instructions. I copied the content of "localtexmf" into the appropriate local folder which is used by TeXLive and I ran the steps which I found here, basically,

https://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

and my situation on this machine is that:

1. Fonts mtpro (Math Time Pro) do work. Great.
2. No way Lucida fonts work. Bad.

Of course I can provide copies of messages I get.

Does anyone have a clue about this? Under MikTeX all OK but not under TeXLive? What's the difference?

Thanks
Maurizio

PS: I unistalled MacTeX completely, I installed it again and now I am back to square one. I jus posted on the lucida mailing list and see if they can suggest something, before I try again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: well if you want help you should write more about the exact pathes where you installed the fonts, the steps you did and the error message you get.